# REACT.JS - addOrder function sometimes work sometimes it doesn't --> newCast error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, e-commerce, mern

So I'm building an e-commerce application using MERN tech stack. Everything is working fine except for my addOrder function which lets the account/user add a product to his/her cart. I was able to make it work but somehow it started getting errors a few hours later. I'm certain that I did not change/edit the code block. What's more weird is that the function works on some users I created but and the bug persists on the others. I tried removing all users and creating new documents and now all users are not able to use the addOrder function.

Code snippet below:

```
module.exports.addOrder = async (req, res) => {

let newOrder

if(req.account.isAdmin){
    return res.send(false)
} 

let account = await Account.findById(req.account.id).then(account => {

    if(account.orderId === ""){

        newOrder = new Order({
            accountId: req.account.id
        }) 

        newOrder.save()
        .then(order => {
            account.orderId = order.id
            account.save()
            return order
        })
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
    }

    return account
})

let order = await Order.findById(account.orderId).then(order => {

    let newProduct

    Product.findById(req.body.productId).then(product => {

        console.log(product);

        if(!product.isActive){
            return res.send({message: "Out of stock!"})
        }

        newProduct = {
            productId: product.id,
            name: product.name,
            price: product.price
        }

        order.transactions.push(newProduct)

        order.totalAmount += product.price

        order.save()
        .then(order => true)
        .catch(err => err.message)

        return res.send({message: "Product added to cart"})
        A
    })
})
```

};

Then here is the error from the terminal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP6yf.png)

I wonder why it encountered bugs when it was completely functional a few hours before I encountered errors. **I noticed that I started encountering errors when I was trying to add orders using the react app. But when I was adding orders prior via postman, it was working.** This might help.

Please let me know if you guys need more info. I've been trying to solve this for the past 2 months. I'm in a slump.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! I attached a photo that shows the error I'm specifically encountering in the terminal when I run my addOrder function. Does that help?